# C# TheMovieDB serializer.Deserialize returns 0 records

Tags: c#, serialization, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to retrieve data from the TheMovieDB API with C#.
I don't want to use external libraries now, because I want to get better in C#.

TheMovieDB API returns me the following:

[image]

I have the following classes:

```
    public class raizDoJson
    {
        public int pagina { get; set; }
        public int totalRegistros { get; set; }
        public int totalPaginas { get; set; }
        public List<serie> series { get; set; }
    }

    public class serie
    {
        public string original_name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int vote_count { get; set; }
        public double vote_average { get; set; }
        public string poster_path { get; set; }
        public string first_air_date { get; set; }
        public int popularity { get; set; }
        public List<generos> genre_ids { get; set; }
        public string original_language { get; set; }
        public string backdrop_path { get; set; }
        public string overview { get; set; }
        public List<paises> origin_country { get; set; }
    }

    public class generos{
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class paises {
        public string pais { get; set; }
    }
```

Next I try to deserialize it:

```
    public static void lerDados(string query)
    {
        string api = " API KEY";
        string endereco = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key={0}&query={1}";
        string url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string.Format(endereco, api, query));

        Console.WriteLine(url);
        Console.ReadKey();

        var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as System.Net.WebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;

        string conteudo;
        using (var resposta = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (var leitor = new System.IO.StreamReader(resposta.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                conteudo = leitor.ReadToEnd();
                //var estrutura = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<raizDoJson>(conteudo);
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var estrutura = serializer.Deserialize<raizDoJson>(conteudo);
            }
        }
    }
```

At end, `conteudo` gets this value:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "total_results": 2,
  "total_pages": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "original_name": "The Big Bang Theory",
      "id": 1418,
      "name": "The Big Bang Theory",
      "vote_count": 3100,
      "vote_average": 6.82,
      "poster_path": "\/ooBGRQBdbGzBxAVfExiO8r7kloA.jpg",
      "first_air_date": "2007-09-24",
      "popularity": 319.823,
      "genre_ids": [
        35
      ],
      "original_language": "en",
      "backdrop_path": "\/nGsNruW3W27V6r4gkyc3iiEGsKR.jpg",
      "overview": "The Big Bang Theory is centered on five characters living in Pasadena, California: roommates Leonard Hofstadter and Sheldon Cooper; Penny, a waitress and aspiring actress who lives across the hall; and Leonard and Sheldon's equally geeky and socially awkward friends and co-workers, mechanical engineer Howard Wolowitz and astrophysicist Raj Koothrappali. The geekiness and intellect of the four guys is contrasted for comic effect with Penny's social skills and common sense.",
      "origin_country": [
        "US"
      ]
    },
    {
      "original_name": "The Big Bang",
      "id": 20261,
      "name": "The Big Bang",
      "vote_count": 2,
      "vote_average": 5.5,
      "poster_path": "\/9ZQX9aujbfd3N4FMVf16FwLRg0K.jpg",
      "first_air_date": "1996-04-15",
      "popularity": 0.079,
      "genre_ids": [
        9648
      ],
      "original_language": "en",
      "backdrop_path": null,
      "overview": "The Big Bang is a CITV science show that broadcast from April 15, 1996 - September 8, 2004, produced by Yorkshire Television. It is notable for being one of CITV's longest-running science programmes. The aim of the programme was to make science fun and interesting for children.",
      "origin_country": [
        "GB"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But `estrutura` has no records... Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The classes shown do not match the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes shown do not match the JSON.

Update your classes to match the data being returned from the API

```
public class raizDoJson {
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int total_results { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
    public List<resultado> results { get; set; }
}

public class resultado {
    public string original_name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int vote_count { get; set; }
    public double vote_average { get; set; }
    public string poster_path { get; set; }
    public string first_air_date { get; set; }
    public int popularity { get; set; }
    public List<string> genre_ids { get; set; }
    public string original_language { get; set; }
    public string backdrop_path { get; set; }
    public string overview { get; set; }
    public List<string> origin_country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand where. I checked it a lot of times and for me it looks like a match... I know that the most common cause of this situation is the classes not matching, but I can't see where...

Comment: @DanielCastro Compare the class I have above to the classes you have. in `raizDoJson` you had portuguese property names while the JSON had english. The result object has string arrays for country and genre but you used classes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that the name of the fields had to be the same. That solved my problem !